# Create a 3d array consisting of vectors

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Here is a very quick one which should be simple to answer if I can explain myself adequately.

I want to create a 144 x 96 x 10000 array called A such that

```
A(1,1,:) = 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004 0.005 0.006 0.007 0.008 0.009 0.010....10000 etc.
....
A(144,96,:) = 0.001 0.002 0.003 0.004 0.005 0.006 0.007 0.008 0.009 0.010....10000 etc.
```

I assume I should use a combination of ones and repmat but I cant seem to figure this one out.

Thanks.

Comment: So in any X,Y vaue you have the whole array?

Comment: But.... Thats a huge array, will you have enough memory?

Comment: Yes and I may end up making it smaller, say, 1:10:10000. However, I would still like to know the principal.

Comment: If the last value of `A(1,1,:)` is 10000 as in your first line, then `A` is 144 x 96 x 1e7, not 144 x 96 x 1e4

Comment: Also, consider if you really need that 3D array. Sometimes you can avoid it using `bsxfun` with your original `0.001 0.002 0.003...` 1D-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permute will kill you on large arrays,... you can also try:

```
array= 0.001:0.001:1000;
A = repmat(reshape(array,1,1,numel(array)),[144 96 1]);
```

Comment: Ops,I though permute didnt copypasted the variables but just change memory access.

Comment: Yes, this route is certainly much faster ;). Thanks to both of you though for the advice

Answer (score 1):

you could do it the following way:

```
array=0.001:0.001:1000;
M=permute(repmat(array,144,1,96),[1 3 2])
```

It  looks like `repmat` doesn't like `[144,96,1]` so we will create it in other size and then just change the order of the dimensions with `permute`

Comment: permute is usually a bad solution with large arrays, as it implies some memory copy/displacement. One should always prefer solutions involving reshape which does not move the data but only changes the way it is viewed.